# Trouble with xsd namespaces

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to get a valid xsd schema for this xml. Some elements belong to the default namespace, other to the b-namespace. It is far from complete, but i'm stuck at the `room` definition. It shows this error:

```
Warning 1   The element 'rooms' in namespace 'building' has invalid child element 'room'. List of possible elements expected: 'room' in namespace 'building'.
```

How do i define the room type in the correct namespace?

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<b:building xmlns:b="building">
  <b:rooms>
    <room>101</room>
    <room>102</room>
    <room>201</room>
  </b:rooms>
  <b:occupations>
    <occupation datum="2012-06-30">
      <room nummer="101">Comment</room>
      <room nummer="102"/>
    </occupation>
    <occupation datum="2012-07-01">
      <room nummer="101"/>
      <room nummer="201">Comment 2</room>
    </occupation>
  </b:occupations>
</b:building>
```

xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="building"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            attributeFormDefault="qualified"
            xmlns="building"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="building">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="rooms">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="room" type="room" />
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="occupations">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="occupation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:complexType name="room">

  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema >
```

Comment: Side note - namespace prefixes only have meaning within a single XML file - your elements don't belong to the "b" namespace - they belong to the `building` namespace. Another XML document starting with `<n:building xmlns:n="building">` would be *exactly* the same, from an information perspective.

Comment: Another side note: the element declaration for occupation has an implicit type of xsd:anyType, which means that it will accept anything inside it.

Answer (score 0):

The elements room and occupation in your XML document have no prefix. Since there is also no default namespace in scope, they are considered, in XML Schema terminology, to be unqualified as they do not belong to the the building namespace.

In your schema, you need to add form="unqualified" to say so in each of the elements for which this applies.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="building"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  attributeFormDefault="qualified"
  xmlns="building"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="building">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="rooms">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element form="unqualified" name="room" type="xsd:integer" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="occupations">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="occupation" form="unqualified" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema >
```

The above schema has two more edits on the room element declaration: a maxOccurs, and an integer type.

I successfully checked validity of your document against the above schema.

An alternate solution is to add the b: prefix in front of room and occupation in your original document. Then you can removed form="unqualified" from the schema.